# Read capacity cost of a DynamoDB table scan

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

It's unclear to me, after reading the docs, how many read capacity units are consumed during a scan operation with a filter in DynamoDB. For example, with this ruby request:

```
table.items.where(:MyAttribute => "Some Value").each do |item_data|
   # do something with the item_data
end
```

My understanding is that this will result in a table scan but DynamoDB will only return the items that I'm interested in. But if my table has 10000 items, and only 5 of those items are what gets through my filter, am I still being "charged" for a huge number of read capacity units?

The attribute I'm using for the filter is not a hash, range or secondary index. I've just had to add that attribute recently, and unexpectedly, which is why I'm not using a query instead.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In short, you will be "charged" for the total amount of items scanned (not the total amount of items returned). **Scan** is, compared to **query** (as you already mentioned) an expensive operation.

Worth mentioning is the fact that when you invoke a scan on a table, it does not mean that the whole table will be scanned. If the size of the scanned items exceeds the limit of 1MB, the scan stops and you have to invoke it again to scan the next portion of the table.

This is taken from the official docs:

> If the total number of scanned items exceeds the maximum data set size
>   limit of 1 MB, the scan stops and results are returned to the user as
>   a LastEvaluatedKey value to continue the scan in a subsequent
>   operation. The results also include the number of items exceeding the
>   limit. A scan can result in no table data meeting the filter criteria.

The filter is applied after the scan on the found items so it does not affect the throughput capacity at all.

If you are going  to be performing these operations regularly, it may be worth considering an addition of some secondary indexes or optimizing the hash and range keys.

Comment: How long would it take to scan my table with 1000 records if my read capacity is 5 read units. If scanning each item uses one read capacity it would take long time to complete the scan right?

Comment: @iamprem "...it would take long time to complete the scan right?". No, it wouldn't, it will still be incredibly fast. And that's what confuses me. Do AWS operate some sort of read/write credit allowance that you build up over time if you're not querying your table?

Comment: Remember when you scan or query, RCU are consumed not based on number of items but the total size of items. If have 1000 records and each is 40 bytes (40,000 bytes total), scanning that table will consume 40,000 / 4,000 * 0.5 = 5 RCU.

Comment: @RTF DynamoDB provides [burst capacity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-partition-key-design.html#bp-partition-key-throughput-bursting), essentially the unused part of your provisioned capacity for the last five minutes.

Comment: I don't understand why neither AWS or any of the SDKs I know of don't provide a cursor.