# Host a python script on web server and get its output for further use

Tags: python, unity-game-engine

I have a unity AR application that needs to run a python script on some event. What I want to do is to host the script on a cloud server, run the script on event from my AR app and use the results generated by python script for future use. I have seen people recommend Ironpython but its not what I need. And according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59855167/running-a-python-program-in-unity-on-android) answer the best way to do this by a cloud hosting.
I have researched it a lot and have found that it is done by making a docker container and then hosting the container to web server. Is this the right way? or can it be done in some other easier work around? The most important part is to trigger that python script from and unity app event and its results should be returned to the app so that it can be used further. Is this doable?

I have never run (or even hosted) a python script over any server and have no basic knowledge of doing it. It would be of great help if anyone could tell me how to do this. Which cloud server would be the best for it and would that server be paid?

This is for my Final year project purpose, any sort of help will be great. Thanks

Comment: Sorry but you need to do some research and read book or blog posts or tutorials. This site is meant to help people on a specific programming issue or to explain some language internals.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud hosting, probably digitalocean? Cheap and efficient, definetly paid server however check in if you can use Heroku somehow?.